# What is the difference between these two functions in Python?

Tags: python

Can anyone explain to me the difference between the two functions here and what is the reason that I am getting two different values?

**1.**

```
def longest_consec(starr, k):
    n = len(starr)
    if n == 0 or k > n or k <= 0 :
        return ""  
    for i in range(n-k+1):
        lst = starr[i:i+k]
        return ''.join(lst)

print(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"], 2))
```

Output: `libezas`

**2.**

```
def longest_consec(strarr, k):
    n = len(strarr)
    if n == 0 or k > n or k <= 0 :
        return ""
    lst = [''.join(strarr[i:i+k]) for i in range(len(strarr)+1-k)]
    return lst

print(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"], 2))
```

Ouput: `['zoneabigail', 'abigailtheta', 'thetaform', 'formlibe', 'libezas']`

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Is `return ''.join(lst)` meant to happen in the first iteration of the loop? Also note that the 1st method returns a string, while the second returns a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def longest_consec(starr, k):
    n = len(starr)
    if n == 0 or k > n or k <= 0 :
        return ""
    for i in range(n-k+1): #this loop is pretty strange, it can be replace by starr[n-k:n] that means create a list with the k last element of starr
        lst = starr[i:i+k]
        #print(lst) -> visualize it
    return ''.join(lst) #concat k last element, ["libe", "zas"] -> "libezas"

def longest_consecbis(strarr, k):
    n = len(strarr)
    if n == 0 or k > n or k <= 0 :
        return ""
    lst = [''.join(strarr[i:i+k]) for i in range(len(strarr)+1-k)] #create an array of string obtained by joining k by k elements (concat)
    #[], k = 2
    #loop 0 -> ["zone, abigail"] -> "zoneabigail" -> add it to the list : result ["zoneabigail"]
    #loop 1 -> ["abigail", "theta"] -> "abigailtheta" -> add it to the list : result ["zoneabigail", "abigailtheta"]
    return lst
```

Adapting the second with the first one look like this :

```
def secondWithOne(starr, k):
    n = len(starr)
    if n == 0 or k > n or k <= 0 :
        return ""
    arr = []
    for i in range(n-k+1):
        arr.append(''.join(starr[i:i+k]))
    return arr
```